# Unable to import shapefile into PostGisDatabase - problem of connection

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgis

I have been trying to import/load a shapefile into a PostGis database without any success despite many trials and searching an answer in the documentation.

**Configuration**
I'm running Windows 64 bits Home (in japanese )
pgAdmin 4
PostgreSQL 12.1
postgis 3

I used 2 differents methods without any results

**METHOD 1 - using the  shp2pgsql-gui.exe/postGis shapefile import gui**

*Here are the connection details
username postgres

password : i put the same password I usually input in pgadmin4

server host "localhost" then for the port  "5432"

database : gis_analysis  (a postgis database)

*And I get the following error message :

> > "unable to connect to the database - please check your connection settings"

and the log message

> > "Connecting:  host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password='*********' dbname=gis_analysis client_encoding=UTF8
> > Connection failed."

*I checked TCPIP to check if the port 5432 was opened
I got 3 sessions of pgadmin4 running on remote port 5432  with a state "established" and some sent packets

**METHOD 2 - using psql/the windows prompt command**

I was planning to use something like this kind of syntax :
shp2pgsql -I -s SRID -W encoding shapefile_name table_name | psql -d database -U
user

But even when I'm running the following command in the prompt command

> > psql -d gis_analysis -U postgres

*I first get a enter the password : the password does not show up in the terminal  but my understanding is that it's normal.
I typed slowly the
I also copied pasted to make sure I don't make a mistake)
*Eithe way I then  get the following error message (for clarity sake,  I get a japanese message but I put here the standard message in english that seems to be used)

> > 'psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgress"'

**BOTTOMLINE**

I can use (import, export, select, alter) a variety of database/tables in pgadmin4 without connection trouble (at worst sometimes it fails because it's too slow but it seems unrelated to me).
I can specifically create a table within my gis_analysis postgis database. I can both import csv file into this table, I can alter/update the table, I can select data from it.
But somehow I cannot import a shapefile
Nor can I use the command prompt, either for the postgis database or any other database.

I am inclined to think it's a username/password problem based on the fact there is no port problem and that I cannot access any kind of database with psql.
But I don't understand why I don't have this connection problem with pgadmin4 and yet when I run either shp2pgsql-gui  or psql  it doesnt work.
I am at my wit's end.
Any insight ?

EDIT : as requested in answer, I m adding a snapshot of connection settings
[image: connection settings]

Comment: Shapefiles or PostGIS have nothing to do with this. Show all the values you've entered on the "Connection" and "SSL" tabs in pgAdmin4.

Comment: @CL  As requested I took a snapshot of all the values in the tab connection and ssl it's in the original post. Truth to be told, I never looked into that/wasnt aware of that. I'm learning through a postgresq book that is really strong on showing how to practically use postgresql/for what purpose but seems light on the settings side. I had to figure out on my own other problems of the same kind before. I'm just stuck on this one and I would really like to move forward on postgis (and psql later on). If you can take a look at the values and give me some insight it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The pgAdmin4 connection goes to the database named "postgres".

Apparently, a database named "gis_analysis" does not exist, or is not configured to accept connection.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm not quite sure though of the exact meaning/the change to implement. No explanation at all in my book about those aspect.

Comment: Did you create that database? Or does your data show up in the "postgres" database in pgAdmin?

Comment: If my memory is correct, postgres was created automatically.  And my understanding it is by design. I did not touch anything/input any data directly in this default database. I created another database called "analysis" to perform all my other manipulations. And yet another one for the Gis data "gis_analysis".  To come back on your earlier comment  : how am I supposed to configure gis_analysis to "accept connection" / how was the earlier page supposed to look like ?

Comment: That would be the [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file.

Comment: I'm coming back late to you. I eventually solved it by granting access to every database to any user in the pg_hba.conf . It's far less elegant than I'd like to and would be a huge no no from a database security standpoint If i understand right. But at least it got me through it for the time being. Thanks for pointing out the pga_hba file. I cannot upvote you because my reputation is too low if i understand right but anyway thanks for the tip.